Multiprocessing Runs Endlessly
I am just trying a basic multiprocessing code in Jupyter notebook, and it seems to run endlessly but it runs okay when I use spyder, not sure why:
from multiprocessing import Pool

def worker(number):
    return number*number

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool() # use all available CPUs
    for square in pool.imap(worker, [0,1,2,3,4]):
        print(square)


I cannot reproduce the issue

Ah, so it's specifically in Jupyter?

@roganjosh yes it is.

Tested the code in Jupyter Notebook in a Linux machine and it worked, it not blocked. You are running in Windows or Linux?

@lewis, running in windows

@roganjosh yes it does resolve my issue, thanks

@UmangGarg no problem. You are able to accept my duplicate suggestion and close the question off; that helps others find the solution without information getting dispersed. Until now, I also didn't know this was an issue with Jupyter
